# Can past perfect be used when referring to a dead person's action, even though there is no previous action?

Tags: past-perfect

I have engaged in a [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129039/discussion-between-loremipsum-and-wade) after trying to change

> *Had* Christopher Tolkien ever publicly spoken about George R. R. Martin or his work?

to

> *Has* Christopher Tolkien ever publicly spoken about George R. R. Martin or his work?

in [this Sci-fi question's title](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253129/had-christopher-tolkien-ever-publicly-spoken-about-george-r-r-martin-or-his-wo).

I have learned that past perfect is used when there are two past actions and one occurs before the other, as in "had Christopher spoken before Jeremy cried?".

The asker, on the other hand, disputes it and upholds that

> When you're talking about someone who is deceased, it is customary to use the pluperfect.

I did not find any authoritative claim to support that. Is it really a thing?

Comment: There are two actions (events) though:one written in the question and one implied (or already known).

Comment: There is a canonical post on ELL discussing the hows, whens and whys of the Present Perfect https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Comment: “it is quite possible to express the same time sequence in a sentence **which permits either a simple past or a past perfect**: 
//OK **Shaw had established** a substantial literary reputation before his first play was produced.
OR //OK  **Shaw established** a substantial literary reputation before his first play was produced.//
In terms of literal meaning, these two sentences amount to the same thing.”

Comment: @LucianSava What is the one implied? Furthermore, in a title, context is not there to imply anything.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, but the quote you mention does contain two past events (one before the other) and as such it does not apply here. Here we only have a single event.

Comment: No one has to specifically mention that CT talked about other authors before his death, it can be implied. Especially if he held talks, lectures and public discussions about literature.  I'd prefer the simple past usage ( Did he ever...) but the Past Perfect sentence is also appropriate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So you are suggesting that the full sentence would be: "Had Christopher Tolkien ever publicly spoken about George R. R. Martin or his work before he held talks, lectures, etc.?" If not, what exactly is the implied action? Or maybe would you dispute that past perfect always needs two past events to occur?

Comment: Now if I wanted an easy 10 points I could agree with you that the Past Perfect must *only* be used in conjunction with a *stated* previous action, but which grammars say that? Both forms (SP and Past P) are valid, and you can either take my word and that of the other two users or leave it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129041/discussion-between-loremipsum-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: You've already been told in a previous comment: **before his death**, or if you need a verb for a better understanding, **before he died**.

Answer (score 1):

"*Has* he ever spoken about..." sounds like he still has the chance to speak if he hasn't spoken yet. So it's not correct, because he's dead.

"Ever" is [often](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ever) used with the perfect tenses, therefore it may indeed be "had he ever spoken." But this one is [rarer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did%20he%20ever%20speak%2Chad%20he%20ever%20spoken&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=17&smoothing=3) than the perfectly fine "did he ever speak."

Comment: But is it correct or not?

Comment: It is, provided that there's a past-perfect-simple signal word (yet, already, never, before, by, just). 'Ever' can be considered as such.

Answer (score 0):

The English perfect is extremely difficult to get right because it has several different meanings. This one is the **existential perfect**, which concerns whether something has happened or not. The perfect can also indicate recency or relevance at a particular moment in time, and someone who is dead is unlikely to have done something recently.

I don't think either "had" or "has" is outright wrong here. If it is in a context where you are discussing Christopher Tolkien, the perfect could be appropriate. But to my ears, the most neutral way to ask the question without additional context is: "**Did** Christopher Tolkien ever **speak publicly** about George R. R. Martin or his work?"

Comment: "If it is in a context where you are discussing Christopher Tolkien, the perfect could be appropriate." Which perfect?

Comment: "Had" if relative to some time in his life: "When he first met George R. R. Martin, had he ever spoken publicly about his work?"

Comment: The example you gave is valid because there are two events, meeting (chronologically the latter) and speaking (chronologically the former). What I would say is that past perfect with a single event does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> **Has Christopher Tolkien ever** publicly **spoken** about George R. R. Martin or his work?

The present Perfect is often used with "ever" to ask about an experience in the past, for example

- **Have you ever seen** the Sistine Chapel?

That person may not have visited the Vatican City or have seen the Sistine Chapel but it does not exclude the possibility of their experiencing that event at some point in the future.

- **Has your child ever eaten** shellfish?

Likewise someone may never have eaten shellfish in their life but this situation could change next week, next month or next year.

The Present Perfect construction is not usually used with people who are dead. It is impossible for Christopher Tolkien, a person who died in January 2020,  to presently speak about Martin. The act of speaking cannot be performed or repeated in the present nor in the future.

It would therefore be more *natural* to ask

> **Did** Christopher Tolkien **ever speak** publicly about George R.R. Martin?

The act is confined to a specific moment in the past.

The original construction using the Past Perfect is also correct; albeit it suggests that **before his death** Christopher Tolkien had discussed works of other writers in public, not only his father's, which is totally plausible.

> [Before his death in 2020] **Had** C.Tolkien **ever spoken** publicly about George R.R. Martin

Comment: About your last paragraph: That would be redundant, wouldn't it? If someone did something that occurred necessarily before his death.

Comment: It's not a given that the son of a famous writer talks in public about other authors. It is **implied** that CT may have.

Comment: But what does CT having or not having talked about other authors has to do with the discussion?

Comment: @LoremIpsum CT was a known personality, he wrote, and curated his father's works. It is *plausible* that he attended lectures, and held talks about his father works and also mentioned the names of other authors BEFORE his death. The "before his death" is implied.